# Write the code for large formula in terms of smaller chunks

Tags: equations

I am wondering if it is possible that for large formulas in order to avoid confusion during code typing, we break it into variables. For example the formula below could be confusing during typing the code and sometimes it is a hassle to debug it. Is it possible that like all computer languages one writes the numerator into a variable and denominator into another one and at the end plugs those variables into the final formula and run it.
thanks

```
\begin{equation}
\hbar \omega_c = I_p+\frac{0.5I_p^{3.5}\lambda^2}{\big[\text{ln}\big(\frac{0.86I_p3^{2n^*-1}G_{lm}C^2_{n^*l^*}}{-\text{ln}(1-p_s)}\tau_p\big)\big]}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Doing this for your readers could help them just as much as doing it for yourself helps you. Why not display the pieces of your final equation in the document, with names you then use in that last equation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can just use `\def` assignments for the smaller groupings of components.  Nesting of these assignments is also permissible, as I show by nesting `\subnum` and `\subdenom` inside of `\demominator`.  And I took Mico's proper suggestion to use `\ln` for the natural log, which will give proper horizontal spacing.

The only proviso in using `\def` instead of `\newcommand` is that you must be careful not to unintentionally overwrite an existing definition of the same name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\def\numerator{0.5I_p^{3.5}\lambda^2}
\def\subnum{0.86I_p3^{2n^*-1}G_{lm}C^2_{n^*l^*}}
\def\subdenom{-\text{ln}(1-p_s)}
\def\denominator{\big[\ln\big(\frac{\subnum}{\subdenom}\tau_p\big)\big]}
\hbar \omega_c = I_p+\frac{\numerator}{\denominator}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately, with display style and `\bigg` in `\denominator`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\def\numerator{0.5I_p^{3.5}\lambda^2}
\def\subnum{0.86I_p3^{2n^*-1}G_{lm}C^2_{n^*l^*}}
\def\subdenom{-\text{ln}(1-p_s)}
\def\denominator{\displaystyle\bigg[\ln\bigg(\frac{\subnum}{\subdenom}\tau_p\bigg)\bigg]}
\hbar \omega_c = I_p+\frac{\numerator}{\denominator}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Instead of `\text{ln}`, I'd write `\ln`, though. I'd also be tempted to insert `\displaystyle` at the start the argument of `\denominator`.